# Why is Azure Data Studio telling me to use sp_configure if Azure SQL does not have it?

Tags: sql-server, docker, azure-sql-database, dacpac, azure-data-studio

When attempting to publish an Azure SQL Database to a container in Docker Desktop, it fails. Why does the error mention the sp_configure procedure if Azure SQL does not contain that procedure?

I've created a SQL Project in Azure Data Studio. I've updated the Schema and now I'm trying to publish to a container. My guess is that I need to configure the database user logins -- though, it is confusing to see the error mentioning a procedure that does not exist in Azure SQL.

What is happening behind the scenes during this deployment that is using authentication?
What authentication process are taking place when publishing an Azure SQL DACPAC to a container?

The errors are displayed below:

```
Deploy dacpac: Could not deploy package.
Warning SQL74501: The source contains users that rely on an external authentication 
provider that is not supported by the target. These users will be treated as users 
without logins.
Error SQL72014: Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 12824, Level 16, State 1, 
Line 5 The sp_configure value 'contained database authentication' must be set to 1 in 
order to alter a contained database. You may need to use RECONFIGURE to set the 
value_in_use.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error. The executed script:
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]
WHERE [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
BEGIN
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
SET FILESTREAM(NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = OFF),
CONTAINMENT = PARTIAL
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
END


Error SQL72014: Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, 
Line 5 ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error. The executed script:
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]
WHERE [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
BEGIN
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
SET FILESTREAM(NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = OFF),
CONTAINMENT = PARTIAL
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
END
```

Image below shows that I am publishing an Azure SQL Database
[image]

Comment: Might try posting this on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)

Comment: First, what is the target db set to in your project, and what SQL Server version is in your container? (It's not Azure SQL0. Please edit and add this info to the question. _The source contains users that rely on an external authentication 
provider that is not supported by the target_  That error makes sense since whatever DB you have inside the container won't support AAD authentication (and Azure SQL does)

Comment: @Nick.Mc Does this show that it is indeed, Azure SQL?

Comment: @Xedni I was torn. Since this is a local db, usually only used by developers, my assumption is that DBAs would actually have less experience with this problem.

Comment: @Nick.Mc I created a new server in our dev environment and then created a new db -- with one table and one user (the sa). I was able to successfully publish. 
I was looking at the JSON in docker and it does say "Labels": {
   "com.microsoft.product": "Microsoft SQL Server",
   "com.microsoft.version": "16.0.4095.4",
   "org.opencontainers.image.ref.name": "ubuntu",
   "org.opencontainers.image.version": "22.04",
   "source": "sqldbproject-basic",
   "vendor": "Microsoft"
  }

So I suppose, that it is SQL Server. So, yeah, more research to do

Comment: So I guess you used the "Azure Database Emulator" in docker? Reading this, it doesn't seem able to support what you are doing without adjustment (it doesn't suppor tAAD authentication) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/local-dev-experience-sql-database-emulator?view=azuresql I wouldn't assume that it doesn't support `sp_configure`. What happens when you try the suggestion here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1161037/import-bacpac-to-local-sql-server-failed-with-sql7

Comment: It really depends on your objectives - are you trying to get a carbon copy of a cloud Azure SQL database into a local emulator (doesn't seem possible) or are you just trying to get the DDL (table definitions etc.) and stuff across?

Comment: _What is happening behind the scenes during this deployment that is using authentication?_ When you created your database project from an existing Azure SQL database, it captured all database users. These users are "Microsoft Entra" users - that is they are Azure cloud logins. The local emulator doesn't support these. If you removed these logins from your database project, this error would probably go away, and you'd be on to the next error. Typically I do not include any security info in my database projects.